# map an array found in a hash to individual hash values

Tags: ruby

I'm getting data from an API and need to format it differently. I have a `car_array` that consists of an array of hashes.  However, sometimes there will be a sub-array as one of the hash values that contains more than 1 element.  In this case, there should be a loop so that each element in the array gets mapped correctly as separate entries.

An example of data, note how `prices` and `options_package` are arrays with multiple elements.

```
[{
  dealer_id: 1,
  dealer_name: "dealership 1",
  car_make: "jeep",
  prices: ['30', '32', '35'],
  options_package: ['A', 'B', 'C']
},  {
  dealer_id: 2,
  dealer_name: "dealership 2",
  car_make: "ford",
  prices: ['50', '55'],
  options_package: ['X', 'Y']
}, {
  dealer_id: 3,
  dealer_name: "dealership 3",
  car_make: "dodge",
  prices: ['70'],
  options_package: ['A']
}]
```

I would like to create multiple entries when there are multiple array elements

for example, the data above should be broken out and mapped as:

```
some_array = [
  { dealer_id: 1, dealer_name: "dealership 1", car_make: "jeep",  price: '30', options_package: 'A' },
  { dealer_id: 1, dealer_name: "dealership 1", car_make: "jeep",  price: '32', options_package: 'B' },
  { dealer_id: 1, dealer_name: "dealership 1", car_make: "jeep",  price: '35', options_package: 'C' },
  { dealer_id: 2, dealer_name: "dealership 2", car_make: "ford",  price: '50', options_package: 'X' },
  { dealer_id: 2, dealer_name: "dealership 2", car_make: "ford",  price: '55', options_package: 'Y' },
  { dealer_id: 3, dealer_name: "dealership 3", car_make: "dodge", price: '70', options_package: 'A' }
]
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
car_arr.each do |car|
  if car['Prices'].length > 1
    # if there are multiple prices/options loop through each one and create a new car 
    car.each do |key, value|
      if key == 'Prices' 
        value.each do |price|
          formatted_car_array << { 
            dealer_id: car['dealer_id'], 
            dealer_name: car['dealer_name'], 
            car_make: car['make'], 
            options_package: ???????, 
            price: price, 
          }
        end
      end
    end                    
  else
    # there's only element for price and options_package 
    formatted_car_array << { 
      dealer_id: car['dealer_id'], 
      dealer_name: car['dealer_name'], 
      car_make: car['make'], 
      options_package: car['options_package'], 
      price: car['prices'] 
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider just one hash to start with, and how this problem can be solved for this simpler problem.

```
h = {
  dealer_id: 1,
  dealer_name: "dealership 1",
  car_make: "jeep",
  prices: ['30', '32', '35'],
  options_package: ['A', 'B', 'C']
}
```

Let's get combinations of prices and options packages using `#zip`.

```
h[:prices].zip(h[:options_package])
# => [["30", "A"], ["32", "B"], ["35", "C"]]
```

The length of `3` for this array corresponds with how many hashes we expect to get from it, so let's map over those, building a new hash each time.

```
h[:prices].zip(h[:options_package]).map do |price, pkg| 
  {
    dealer_id: h[:dealer_id],
    dealer_name: h[:dealer_name],
    car_make: h[:car_make],
    price: price,
    options_package: pkg,
  } 
end
# => [{:price=>"30", :options_package=>"A", :dealership=>nil, :dealer_id=>1, :car_make=>"jeep"},
#     {:price=>"32", :options_package=>"B", :dealership=>nil, :dealer_id=>1, :car_make=>"jeep"}, 
#     {:price=>"35", :options_package=>"C", :dealership=>nil, :dealer_id=>1, :car_make=>"jeep"}]
```

Now you just need to `#flat_map` this over your array.

```
car_arr.flat_map do |h|
  h[:prices].zip(h[:options_package]).map do |price, pkg| 
    {
      dealer_id: h[:dealer_id],
      dealer_name: h[:dealer_name],
      car_make: h[:car_make],
      price: price,
      options_package: pkg,
    } 
  end
end
# => [{:price=>"30", :options_package=>"A", :dealership=>nil, :dealer_id=>1, :car_make=>"jeep"},
#     {:price=>"32", :options_package=>"B", :dealership=>nil, :dealer_id=>1, :car_make=>"jeep"}, 
#     {:price=>"35", :options_package=>"C", :dealership=>nil, :dealer_id=>1, :car_make=>"jeep"}, 
#     {:price=>"50", :options_package=>"X", :dealership=>nil, :dealer_id=>2, :car_make=>"ford"},
#     {:price=>"55", :options_package=>"Y", :dealership=>nil, :dealer_id=>2, :car_make=>"ford"},
#     {:price=>"70", :options_package=>"A", :dealership=>nil, :dealer_id=>3, :car_make=>"dodge"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If `arr` is the array of hashes given in the question one may write the following.

```
arr.flat_map do |h|
  h[:prices].zip(h[:options_package]).map do |p,o|
    h.reject { |k,_| k == :prices }.merge(price: p, options_package: o)
  end
end
  #=> [{:dealer_id=>1, :dealer_name=>"dealership 1", :car_make=>"jeep",
  #     :options_package=>"A", :price=>"30"},
  #    {:dealer_id=>1, :dealer_name=>"dealership 1", :car_make=>"jeep",
  #     :options_package=>"B", :price=>"32"},
  #    {:dealer_id=>1, :dealer_name=>"dealership 1", :car_make=>"jeep",
  #     :options_package=>"C", :price=>"35"},
  #    {:dealer_id=>2, :dealer_name=>"dealership 2", :car_make=>"ford",
  #     :options_package=>"X", :price=>"50"},
  #    {:dealer_id=>2, :dealer_name=>"dealership 2", :car_make=>"ford",
  #     :options_package=>"Y", :price=>"55"},
  #    {:dealer_id=>3, :dealer_name=>"dealership 3", :car_make=>"dodge",
  #     :options_package=>"A", :price=>"70"}]
```

Note that this code need not be changed if key-value pairs are added to the hash or if the keys `:dealer_id` and `:dealer_name` are deleted or renamed.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is an extension upon the [answer of Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74142745/3982562).

> ```
> car_arr.flat_map do |h|
>   h[:prices].zip(h[:options_package]).map do |price, pkg| 
>     {
>       dealer_id: h[:dealer_id],
>       dealer_name: h[:dealer_name],
>       car_make: h[:car_make],
>       price: price,
>       options_package: pkg,
>     } 
>   end
> end
> ```

This answer could be shortened if you're using the newest Ruby version.

[Ruby 3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2020/12/25/ruby-3-0-0-released/) introduced [`Hash#except`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-except), which lets you easily create a copy of a hash without the specified key(s). This allows us to reduce the answer to:

```
cars.flat_map do |car|
  car[:prices].zip(car[:options_package]).map do |price, pkg| 
    car.except(:prices).merge(price: price, options_package: pkg)
  end
end
```

`car.except(:prices)` will create a new hash without the `:prices` key/value-pair, we don't need to remove `:options_package`, since `merge` will overwrite the the old `:options_package` value with a new value.

[Ruby 3.1](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2021/12/25/ruby-3-1-0-released/) introduced `{ x:, y: }` as syntax sugar for `{ x: x, y: y }`. This allows us to "reduce" the answer further to:

```
cars.flat_map do |car|
  car[:prices].zip(car[:options_package]).map do |price, options_package| 
    car.except(:prices).merge(price:, options_package:)
  end
end
```

Comment: It does make the answer a bit longer, since `2 * len(options_package) = 30` and `len(options_package) + 2 * len(pkg) = 21`, but it is more expressive and probably improves readability. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
input = [{
       dealer_id: 1,
       dealer_name: "dealership 1",
       car_make: "jeep",
       prices: ['30', '32', '35'],
       options_package: ['A', 'B', 'C']
     }, {
       dealer_id: 2,
       dealer_name: "dealership 2",
       car_make: "ford",
       prices: ['50', '55'],
       options_package: ['X', 'Y']
     }, {
       dealer_id: 3,
       dealer_name: "dealership 3",
       car_make: "dodge",
       prices: ['70'],
       options_package: ['A']
     }]
```

Code

```
result = input.map do |h|
  prices = h[:prices]
  options_package = h[:options_package]
  h[:options_package].count.times.map do
    h[:prices] = prices.shift
    h[:options_package] = options_package.shift
    h.dup
  end
end

p result.flatten
```

Output

```
[{:dealer_id=>1, :dealer_name=>"dealership 1", :car_make=>"jeep", :prices=>"30", :options_package=>"A"}, 
 {:dealer_id=>1, :dealer_name=>"dealership 1", :car_make=>"jeep", :prices=>"32", :options_package=>"B"}, 
 {:dealer_id=>1, :dealer_name=>"dealership 1", :car_make=>"jeep", :prices=>"35", :options_package=>"C"}, 
 {:dealer_id=>2, :dealer_name=>"dealership 2", :car_make=>"ford", :prices=>"50", :options_package=>"X"}, 
 {:dealer_id=>2, :dealer_name=>"dealership 2", :car_make=>"ford", :prices=>"55", :options_package=>"Y"}, 
 {:dealer_id=>3, :dealer_name=>"dealership 3", :car_make=>"dodge", :prices=>"70", :options_package=>"A"}]
```

Comment: Bear in mind this will mutate the original `hash`, which is not necessarily _wrong_ but does need to be considered. Also `hash` may be a slightly misleading name for an array _of_ hashes.

Comment: hash name might be misleading. Yes. Thanks for letting me know.